# Can't get Applescript to change Paragraph style of text frame in InDesign

Tags: applescript, adobe, stylesheet, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to write a "simple" applescript that will find a text frame in InDesign that has a certain property and then change the Paragraph style of that particular text frame. I know that the if statement is correct because I use it for other applescripts. 
So I have a text frame with the object style called "PriceBox". If the text frame contains a slash "/" in it, I want to change the Paragraph style to "2for". I confirmed that the paragraph style exists in the document. However, when I run the script, I get this error:

error "Can’t set «class psty» of {«class txtf» id 6905 of «class sprd» id 6891 of document id 4 of application \"Adobe InDesign CC 2015\"} to \"2for\"." number -10006 from «class psty» of {«class txtf» id 6905 of «class sprd» id 6891 of document id 4} to «class 2for»

I've tried variations of the "set paragraph style" script and none of them seem to work. Please help! =) Thank you!

tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2015"

```
tell active document
    set horizontal measurement units of view preferences to inches
    set vertical measurement units of view preferences to inches
    repeat with x from 1 to count pages
        set ThisPage to page x
        tell ThisPage
            if exists (text frames whose (name of applied object style is "PriceBox" and contents contains "/$")) then
                set paragraph style of (get text frames whose name of applied object style is "PriceBox") to "2for"
    end if  
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

end tell

Answer (score 0):

You are testing for "/$" not just "/".

You can't apply paragraph style to a text frame directly. You will need to use paragraphs.

Also need to loop through the frames

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2015"
    tell active document
        set horizontal measurement units of view preferences to inches
        set vertical measurement units of view preferences to inches
        repeat with x from 1 to count pages
            set ThisPage to page x
            tell ThisPage
                if exists (text frames whose (name of applied object style is "PriceBox" and contents contains "/$")) then

                    set myFrames to (text frames whose (name of applied object style is "PriceBox" and contents contains "/$")))
                    tell myFrames
                        repeat with r from 1 to count items
                            set applied paragraph style of paragraphs of item r of myFrames to "2For"
                        end repeat
                    end tell
                end if
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```